# IOC registration of custom HttpClientFactory to Flurl without FlurlClient

Tags: c#, .net-core, flurl

Will the following IOC registration work with static extension calls to Flurl? The switch to injecting `FlurlClient` is project wide, so I'm wondering if there is a way to register the `MyFlurlClientFactory` by IOC

```c#
services.AddSingleton<IHttpClientFactory, MyFlurlClientFactory>();
```

Sample static extension call to Flurl.

```c#
string text = await "http://example.com/readme.txt".GetStringAsync();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will not work, because the static extension method knows nothing about instance-based ServiceCollection.

You can achieve that without DI, just by modifying the GlobalSettings at application startup before any flurl requests:

```
FlurlHttp.GlobalSettings.HttpClientFactory = new MyFlurlClientFactory();
```

And then call:

```
string text = await "https://flurl.dev/docs/client-lifetime/#using-flurl-with-an-ioc-container".GetStringAsync();
```

See the fully working example on the [dotnetfiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/Dt1xpq).

See more about [configuration](https://flurl.dev/docs/configuration/).

But the clearest DI-friendly solution I think just use the recommended documentation way - inject the [IFlurlClient](https://flurl.dev/docs/client-lifetime/#using-flurl-with-an-ioc-container).